# Is there a Performance impact if there are 5000+ items with unique item level permissions in a SharePoint Add-in web document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, sharepoint-addin, performance

Around the internet I have read that have unique permissions for items within a document library can affect performance.

Is this still valid for SharePoint online?

I am writing an add-in and want to have unique permissions within a document library that can store upto 5000+ documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's still valid, as it's still a SharePoint.

You can read more about the limits at TechNet site:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

As you can see limitation are the same for SharePoint 2013 on premise and SharePoint online

Comment: thanks for the reply.

In the technet article [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169566.aspx)
there is a line 
"he number of uniquely scoped children is not a significant issue, and can scale to large numbers. The number of principles that will be added as limited access up the chain of scopes to the first uniquely-permissioned web will be a limiting factor"

in my case i wont be having more users. lets assume it may not exceed 100 users. will i have a major performance impact? if i had more unique permissioned items.

Comment: It's not easy to predict... I have discover that very similar tenants configurations can have different behaviours. In general your tenant it's a part of the bigger installation, and if other tenant do not require to much resources it could work, and in other case it could a problem. I have similar problem with workflow which was working perfect in one tenant and in another there were a problem with performance... You have to made a test. Or someone else can share his experience.